# OData service password validation in ABAP

Tags: validation, passwords, odata, abap

How do I validate password using function module  which is stored in Z*** table against the `sy-uname` in ABAP?

I am using function module to create OData service for Fiori app where in the moment user hits on enter button it should display successful else unsuccessful based on sy-uname?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

First,

> **you never ever shouldn't store passwords for your application in plain text**.

It is so obvious that never should be mentioned, but nevertheless. Only hash functions from your passwords should be stored.

Second, following function module should be used for generating hash and validation against it:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'MD5_CALCULATE_HASH_FOR_CHAR'
 EXPORTING
   DATA                 = LV_PASSWORD
 IMPORTING
   HASH                 = STRU-PASSHS.
```

Also, you can check `SECH` function group and modules contained there, but consider that some of them are deprecated.